# how to delete a blank column

Tags: tables, columns, code, tipa, phonetic

[image]I have a table with a blank column that can not be deleted. I have tried a lot but it does not compile. Here is the code:

```
\usepackage{tipa}
\let\ipa\textipa

\begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|cc|cc|cc|cc|cc|cc|cc|cc|cc|cc|cc|}
            \hline & 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\footnotesize{Bilibial}}&                  
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\footnotesize{Lab.dent}} &             
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\footnotesize{Dental}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\footnotesize{Alveolar}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\footnotesize{P.Alvo}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\footnotesize{Paltal}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\footnotesize{Velar}} &                    
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\footnotesize{Uvular}} &                   
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\footnotesize{Phar}} &             
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\footnotesize{Lar}}\\                  
            \hline Plosive &                            
                p & b &                                                  
                &&                                       
                t & d &
                &&
                &&
                &&
                k & \textscriptg &                                                   
                 & q &                                      
                & \BlankCell        & \ipa{P}                               
                 &      \\      
                \hline Affricative &                            
                       &  &                                                  
                & &                                      
                & &
                & &
                 \textteshlig&\textdyoghlig  &
                & &
                &  &                                                     
                 &  &
                 & &
                 & &                                        
                     \\                             
                        
                                         \hline Fricative &                             
                &  &                                                     
                f & v&                                       
                &  &
                s &z&
                \ipa{S} & \ipa{Z} &
                &&
                x & \textgamma &                                                    
                 &  & 
\textcrh & \ipa{Q} 
                 & h &                                                          
                                                   \\                               

            \hline Nasal&                           
                & m &                                                   
                &  &                                            
                                                
                & n &                                                                                   
                & & 
                & &                                                 
                &&                                                      
                & \ipa{N} &                                                                                                     
                & &
                & &  
                & &     \\      

            \hline Trill &                                  
                & &                                         
                & & 
                & &                                                  
                & {r}&                              
                & &                             
                & & 
                & &                                                      
                & & 
                & &                                 
                & &                                                     
                \BlankCell         \\       

            \hline Tap &    
            & &                                         
                & & 
                & &                                                  
                & {\textfishhookr}&                             
                & &                             
                & & 
                & &                                                      
                & & 
                & &                                 
                & &                                                     
                \BlankCell         \\                       
                
            
            \hline Lateral &                    
                & &             
                & &             
                &  &                
            l   & \textsuperimposetilde{l} &            
                                                                            
                & &                                                      
                & &                                                      
                & &                                                      
                & &                                                      
                & &         
                & &               \\   

            \hline Glide &                          
                & w &           
                & &             
                & &                 
                & &                                                         
                & j &                                                        
                & &                                                      
                & &                                                      
                & &                                                      
                & &         
                & &           \\        

            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
```

Comment: Please read about [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to know how to format a question. As it is, 1) your code isn't compilable because it's incomplete, and 2) you mention compile-time errors but don't give the error message.

Comment: 1. Your first cell has “Trill”, but that is not in your code, How does it come there?

Comment: 2, There is one `cc|` too many in your column description.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, just an **analysis**. If your code example does not compile, what it doesn't, it didn't compile before you introduced all the details of the table.
E.g. it's not clear why you'd need package `tipa`. For language specific things have a look at `babel`, at https://ctan.org/pkg/babel . For basic table design have a look here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables .

**Compile problems** of your posted code with Texmaker (MikTex distribution)
[image: no compile]

**Suggestions**:

- start small, see code below
- compile, see it passing
- add a small new chunk of code
- repeat, until you arrived where you wanted to go
- i.e. don't do too many things in one go, hoping for the best

Start e.g. here:

[image: hi-image]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
    
\begin{document}
hi
\end{document}
```

Following this approach the next step could look like this, with some intermediate edit&compile steps left out, moving towards the target step by step in a safe way:

[image: next iterations]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{|l|lr|lr|}
        \hline
        Plosive     &p&b &  &  \\\hline
        Affricative & &  &  &  \\\hline
        Fricative   & &  &f &v \\\hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it will be compiled but with that extra column

Comment: Which compilation do you use? // Your code misses Latex basics.

Comment: Please write the code for this table for me. You can put X in internal cells

Comment: See above. // Which compiler or Latex-environment do you use?